# Why I can't provide an in-class initializer for std::vector data member

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to initialize the member `vec` within the class scope, but the compiler throws a more cryptic error.

```
class A {
public:
    static const size_t sz = 10;
    static const std::vector<double> vec{ sz }; // error
};
```

The compiler (gcc) gives the following error(s):

```
error: in-class initialization of static data member 'std::vector<double> A::vec' of non-literal type
   10 |     static std::vector<double> vec{ sz };
      |                                ^~~
error: non-constant in-class initialization invalid for non-inline static member 'A::vec'
   10 |     static std::vector<double> vec{ sz };
      |                                        ^
note: (an out of class initialization is required)
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Notice the message saying "non-constant in-class initialization invalid for **non-inline** static member..." (emphasis mine)? That's a hint about how to solve your problem.

Comment: With that said, why do you want a *constant* vector? You can't modify the contents of it. Even assignment like `vec[0] = 5.0` is invalid.

Comment: Dupe: [Initialize a static const non-integral data member of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490451/initialize-a-static-const-non-integral-data-member-of-a-class). Another dupe: [Why are only static const integral types & enums allowed In-class Initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656941/why-cant-i-initialize-non-const-static-member-or-static-array-in-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, *static* data members may not be initialized in the class body. However, we can provide in-class initializers for static members that are only of `const`-qualified integral type. If non-integral static members are used, and you need to provide an in-class initializer, the data member shall be `constexpr` literal type. In any case, the initializers must be constant expressions. If the type of the member is not literal type (hence `constexpr` can't be used), the static member shall not have a default member initializer, instead, it can be defined outside the class.

So your error is just because `std::vector<double>` is of non-integral type. Also, you can't declare `vec` as constexpr because `std::vector<double>` is not a literal type.

So to fix your above example, you can do this:

```
class A {
public:
    static const size_t sz = 10;
    static const std::vector<double> vec;
};

const std::vector<double> A::vec{ sz };
```

([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T78Gh4xdj))

As pointed out in the commnets, note that, making `vec` `const`-qualified, you will lose some of the vector features. For example, you can't modify any element after adding it!